# Multivariate Polynomial at least $k^n$ roots and i-th degree less than $k$ is the zero polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I've been trying to figure out this problem for some time now and am stuck: consider a multivariate polynomial $r(x_1 , \ldots , x_n) \in \mathbb{ C } [x_1 , \ldots , x_n]$.  Let $k$ be a fixed, arbitrary positive integer.  Suppose we know that $r$ has at least $k^n$ roots in $\mathbb{ C }^n $.  For each $i = 1 , \ldots , n$ we may regard $r$ as living in $\left( \mathbb{ C } [x_1 , \ldots , x_{i-1} , x_{i+1}, \ldots, x_n] \right)[x_i]$; we can write 
$$
 r = b_{i,0}(x_1 , \ldots , x_{i-1} , x_{i+1} , \ldots , x_n) + b_{i,1}(x_1 , \ldots , x_{i-1} , x_{i+1} , \ldots , x_n) x_i + \ldots + b_{i,d_i}(x_1 , \ldots , x_{i-1} , x_{i+1} , \ldots , x_n) x_i ^{d_i}
$$
for $b_{i,j}(x_1 , \ldots , x_{i-1} , x_{i+1} , \ldots , x_n) \in \mathbb{ C } [x_1 , \ldots , x_{i-1} , x_{i+1} , \ldots , x_n]$ for $1 \le i \le d_i$.
Suppose we also know that $d_i < k$ for all $i=1 , \ldots , n$.  In other words the ``i-th'' degree of $r$ is strictly less than $k$ for all $i = 1, \ldots , n$.  With these two hypotheses, may we conclude that $r$ is the zero polynomial?  If yes, how does the argument go?

Comment: If $n>1$ and $r$ is non-constant, $r$ has infinitely many zeroes, so I am not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from @Mohan's comment, you can actually show that $r$ has an infinite number of zeros if the field is infinite.
Think of all the algebraic curves: conics, cubics etc.

However you can show that if $r$ has a zero set of the form of a product then you have your conclusion. MAybe this will help you.
I'm going to work with a field $F$

**Induction Hypothesis**: For all polynomials $r\in F[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ which is of degree $d_i <k$ in the $X_i$ variable, if $r$ is zero on a set 
$Z_1\times\ldots\times Z_n$ with $|Z_i|=k$ then $r=0$

**n=1**: You know this. A one variable polynomial of degree $d$ has at most $d$ roots.

**Heredity**: You write your polynomial:

$$r(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=\sum_{i=0}^{d_n} b_i (X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1})\cdot X_n ^i$$
then $\forall (z_1,\ldots,z_{n-1})\in Z_1\times\ldots\times Z_{n-1}$ the polynomial $r(z_1,\ldots,z_{n-1},X_n)$ has $k$ roots but is of degree at most $d_n<k$ thus is the 0 polynomial. So we are in the followng situation:

$$\forall i \quad\forall (z_1,\ldots,z_{n-1})\in Z_1\times\ldots\times Z_{n-1},
\quad b_i(z_1,\ldots,z_{n-1})=0$$

By induction you get:
$$\forall i\quad b_i=0$$
So you get $r=0$

**Last Comment**: Now that all this is done, you can actually replace your field $F$ with any kind of integral domain and the proof still works.

Comment: Wow-yes in fact this is exactly the situation that I was in.  I doubt I would have come up with this on my own: thanks!